# Can't open the Terminal!

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I used to be able to open the terminal by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut; however, now I can't. Even if I click on the Terminal executable in my applications, it doesn't open the terminal. The only way I can open it is by using right-click on the desktop and pressing 'open the terminal'.

How can I fix this issue and access the terminal both with the shortcut keys and Terminal executable icon in the applications?

Answer (score 1):

**Open your menu to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Scroll down in the window and find the shortcut for “Run a Terminal”.**

Check the shortcut, if doesn't exist,  create of your own ( Ctrl + Alt + T )

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer and if it doesn't work then try 
`Super + a` and then type terminal.